# Upgrade to Rails 4.2 breaks rspec feature specs - why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

My model and controller specs are running fine, but after the upgrade to rails 4.2, my feature specs, which use Capybara, no longer work.  Example:

```
#in spec_helper.rb:
def login_admin
  create(:user,
         first_name: 'John',
         last_name: 'Doe',
         email: 'doej@test.com',
         admin: true)

  visit root_path
  fill_in 'email', with: 'doej@test.com'
  fill_in 'password', with: 'password1'
  click_button 'Log in'
  puts 'created'
end

#in spec/features/albums_spec.rb
feature "Albums", :type => :feature do
  before(:each) do
    login_admin
  end

  scenario 'do something' do
    save_and_open_page
  end
end
```

When I run this spec, it never finishes, either pass or fail.  No error is thrown; it just sits there, showing Albums with the cursor beneath.  'created' is never put to stdout, and the page is never launched by the `save_and_open_page` call.  Test log shows the erb file is rendered by my login action.  This was all working prior to the rails 4.2 upgrade.

This only fails during the spec run - using the app in the browser works fine.

What am I missing here?

Comment: as part of the upgrade did rspec get upgraded as well?

Comment: @Doon - no it was already at the latest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE: possible problems related to capybara/rspec:

1. Avoid creating models in feature specs, because they're created in a different thread. Instead, create the user using capybara steps (i.e. "sign up" the user every time).
2. If you really need the database prepared for scenario in a way impossible to create from clicking around the site, implement a simple "admin" area in your app (you'll probably need one anyway) or admin API interface or something like a CSV upload option, etc.
3. Otherwise, you can search for "capybara rspec database_cleaner append_after" for a setup to support creating models in feature specs, but I've found that none of the solutions are really bullet-proof. You could try: https://github.com/RailsApps/rails_apps_testing

I'm guessing your example is/was stuck on a database operation (waiting for db connection in other threads to end).

PREVIOUS ANSWER:

A few ideas:

1. catch exceptions in the login_admin method and print them out using `STDERR.puts`
2. remove the click_button and see if it fails as expected (shows you the login page)
3. add a `sleep 4` after the password is typed in
4. separate the click_button into 2 calls (to see which one hangs):

   ```
   btn = find(:button, locator, options)
   STDERR.puts "found: #{btn.inspect}"
   btn.click
   ```
5. use `bundle show capybara` to find out where it is, edit the find (or click) method and put in STDERR.puts methods there to see what's wrong

Comment: This turned out to be an issue with perhaps not using rspec correctly on my part.  After some refactoring, it 's now working correctly.  Still, good troubleshooting tips.